# Common Cable/Connector with (at least) 24 parallel conductors (USB/DVI/LVDS/etc.)

Tags: usb, connector, cables, lvds

I'm designing a special device that needs 24 parallel connections to the outer world. Of course compact solution is of preference. Kinda like flex cable, but it must be durable, and the end user will actually use it and plug it into different stuff frequently (I hope). To be precise, it will be plugged into adapter boards that will convert my connections into all kinds of different port.

**To put it simple**: my (prototype) device is supposed to have a cable sticking out of it, the cable must have 24 independent conductors (or more, obviously). I could use two ports if the solution is neat and relatively space efficient (3cm x 5cm max), but one port is the preference.

They will be used for low current DC (strictly 10ma per pin max, all the way down to microamps).

Of course, the first idea was USB Type-C. Small, compact, common. The problem is, all cables have GND pins or power pins connected with each other internally. I haven't found a Type-C Cable with 24 independent conductors. If such cable exists, just give me a link and we're effectively done here (and an ocean of gratitude from me).

Another good solution would be, apart from 24-conductor Type-C cable, a 30-pin LVDS connector, except that hyperintense "googling" and "mousering" only give plastic LVDS connectors, while I would be totally happy to have a metal LVDS connector like in Macbooks, because I believe it would be durable enough and it's compact. But I just couldn't find it anywhere except Aliexpress, which is not the way to go, I need a part with proper datasheet and/or footprint (I can make a footprint from datasheet if I have to).

Macbook LVDS connector, which I just can't find on any respectable part seller's website:
[image]

I spent hours on mouser and digikey, but the only solution I found is the DVI-I dual link, which, if you look at the pinout, does, in fact, provide 24 1-to-1 connections. It is a little bulky tho. So I decided to ask the community if there's some reasonable alternative I have overlooked.

I looked at all kinds of connections like HDMI, but they all have too few pins.

EDIT: D-sub connectors are a good idea. I never looked at those. They're common enough in terms of cables and they still have reasonable size. Thank you.

Comment: Can you actually define "relatively space efficient" with a definite maximum size? Without you giving us a number of a maximum size, the best we can do is the same that you can do: go to digikey.com and open up the list of connectors. I don't know whether "relatively compact" is 6cm×1cm, 5cm×1cm, 1cm×1cm, or 4mm×2mm.

Comment: There are no strict definitions. Type-C is good, DVI is on the border. HDMI sized and smaller is best. I don't have space restriction on PCB, but it would be weird if the user had to play with massive IDE cable from ancient hard drives (yes, I considered even that for a bit). Whatever is smaller than DVI/VGA will do

Comment: no, it doesn't work that way. Give us a maximum number. For a thousand euros, you can get something incredibly small, incredibly fragile. Do you need something 4mm × 4mm? probably not. Please state requirements.

Comment: [Amp connector like this?](https://ni.scene7.com/is/image/ni/SCSI_Connector?scl=1). [National Instruments connector like this?](https://ni.scene7.com/is/image/ni/LFH_Connector_Image?scl=1)

Comment: @Andyaka it is on a larger side, but it looks like I could maybe consider it. What is the exact name of the thing so that I mouser it up? (Amp connector)

Comment: @MarcusMüller 3cm x 5cm max, if you like specific number than much. And the connector shouldn't cost more than 10 bucks, it should be a common type with cables that preferably could be found in most electronics stores, not some weird uncommon connectors

Comment: Dunno. I knew I'd seen them on various things so I was just letting you know of their existence.

Comment: @Andyaka what is their name exactly? how do I find them on mouser/digikey?

Comment: Maybe here: https://www.mouser.co.uk/Connectors/D-Sub-Connectors/D-Sub-High-Density-Connectors/_/N-9gy6q

Comment: @Andyaka much appreciated. I hope matching cables exist for at least some of them there. I will look through them all. Thank you.

Comment: No problem @Ilya - I gave assistance despite it being off-topic because you do take the trouble of accepting answers i.e. you "play the game". However, it is off topic so it will likely be closed but I can see you have several leads now so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 3cm x 5cm max

OK, then good old robust D-sub 25 pin will be your choice. The same kind you found on computers, back when printers where attached using a parallel printer port!

These are cheap, very robust, and the full-sized connector including the fastening screws is 53mm and 11mm high, making the connector itself less than 5cm wide.

There's also higher-density versions of sub-d, but given your requirements, these are totally unnecessary.

Since parallel printer cables are now essentially very hard to sell, they've become cheap.

Comment: I'm afraid at the time when printers were connected like that, I couldn't even walk haha. But I will look at them. I hope I will find matching cables. Thank you!

Comment: @Ilya you're young! The last consumer parallel port printer I saw on sale was around 2005!

Comment: okay well I'm slightly older than that (25), but I guess it's not relevant here. In any case, thank you for an idea. I basically needed some fresh idea for inspiration, preferably from experienced people like you and Andy aka. I'm wondering if it's your full time job to reply here because your scores are something out of this world...

Comment: @Ilya ah, no, Andy and I work full time as dancers on Ibiza, as a matter of fact. However, we sometimes spend a bit of time on the side here.

Comment: It is easy to make your own cables using D-Subminature connectors, particularly if you use the types with insertable contacts that are crimped on the wires, then inserted in the connector body (with a suitable crimp tool, of course).